# Bootstrap-table Getting click error on my data-formmatter checkboxes

Tags: bootstrap-table

I have a list of people that can be teachers or students (but not both).  I have json data

```
{id:0,name:joe,isStudent:0,IsTeacher:0}
```

as the source for a bootstrap-table.  I have used the column's data-formatter to format the the checkboxs in 2 columns

```
                function formatStudent(value, row, index) {
                return '<input type="checkbox" id="d_' + row["id"] +'"' + ((value != 0) ? ' checked ' : '') + '>';
            }
```

There is another formatter for the Teacher column.The bootstrap-table renders properly with 2 checkboxes per row however, when I click on a checkbox - i get an error **"Cannot read property of 'click' of undefined**.

Answer (score 1):

you can use 'data-events' to handle your events:

html:

```
<table id="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="name">Name</th>
        <th data-field="isStudent"
            data-formatter="formatStudent"
            data-events="studentEvents">Is Student</th>
        <th data-field="isTeacher" 
            data-formatter="teacherStudent"
            data-events="teacherEvents">Is Teacher</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

js:

```
var data = [
    {id: 0, name: 'joe1', isStudent: 0, isTeacher: 0},
    {id: 1, name: 'joe2', isStudent: 1, isTeacher: 0},
    {id: 2, name: 'joe3', isStudent: 0, isTeacher: 1},
    {id: 3, name: 'joe4', isStudent: 1, isTeacher: 1},
    {id: 4, name: 'joe5', isStudent: 0, isTeacher: 0}
];

$(function () {
    $('#table').bootstrapTable({
        data: data
    });
});

function formatStudent(value, row, index) {
    return '<input type="checkbox" id="d_' + row["id"] +'"' + ((value != 0) ? ' checked ' : '') + '>';
}

window.studentEvents = {
    'click :checkbox': function (e, value, row, index) {
        // do something
    }
};

function teacherStudent(value, row, index) {
    return '<input type="checkbox" id="d_' + row["id"] +'"' + ((value != 0) ? ' checked ' : '') + '>';
}

window.teacherEvents = {
    'click :checkbox': function (e, value, row, index) {
        // do something
    }
};
```

Docs here: http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/#column-options